# Unable to instantiate receiver com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver while recieving pushes

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

While trying to send push from the OneSignal Platform, getting the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3304)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1771)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.ContextImpl
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3291)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1771) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Using OneSignal Version 3.9.2. Manifest has

```
<service
            android:name="<packageName>.OneSignalNotification"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

And OneSignalNotification extends NotificationExtenderService.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119248/java-lang-classcastexception-android-app-contextimpl)

Comment: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/357 somewhat related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened since in Application class LocaleManager.setLocale was returning ContextWrapper. Changed this to return context and this issue has been fixed

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base));
}
```